# Matching specific unicode char in haskell regexp

Tags: regex, macos, unicode, haskell

**This is Mac/OSX related problem!**

I have the following three character long haskell string:

```
"a\160b"
```

I want to match and replace the middle character

Several approaches like

```
ghci> :m +Text.Regex
ghci> subRegex (mkRegex "\160") "a\160b" "X"
  "*** Exception: user error (Text.Regex.Posix.String died: (ReturnCode 17,"illegal byte sequence"))
ghci> subRegex (mkRegex "\\160") "a\160b" "X"
  "a\160b"
```

did not yield the desired result.

How do I have to modify the regexp or my environment to replace the '\160' with the 'X' ?

The problem seems to have it's root in the locale/encoding of the input.

```
bash> locale
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

I already modified my .bashrc to export the following env-vars:

```
bash> locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

But this did not change the behavior at all.

Comment: What regex package are you using?  This works for me: `Prelude Text.Regex> :m +Text.Regex
Prelude Text.Regex> subRegex (mkRegex "\160") "a\160b" "X"
"aXb"
`

Comment: `'\160'` is `&nbsp`, there might be some funky arcane reason Regex.Posix (in particular) doesn't like it, like normalising it to a normal space.

Comment: My first try was with: regex-base-0.93.2, regex-posix-0.94.2, regex-compat-0.93.1. Then I tried with Text.Regex.TDFA with the same result. I'm on an MacBook here, apparently this code runs on a linux machine, so I suspect some problem with the underlying libs

Answer (score 5):

I was able to reproduce your problem by setting my locale to 'en_US.UTF-8'. (I am also using MacOSX.)

```
bash> export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
bash> ghci                   
GHCi, version 6.12.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :m +Text.Regex
Prelude Text.Regex> subRegex (mkRegex "\160") "a\160b" "X"
"*** Exception: user error (Text.Regex.Posix.String died: (ReturnCode 17,"illegal byte sequence"))
```

Setting your locale to 'C' should fix the problem:

```
bash> export LANG=C
bash> ghci                   
GHCi, version 6.12.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :m +Text.Regex
Prelude Text.Regex> subRegex (mkRegex "\160") "a\160b" "X"
"aXb"
```

Unfortunately, I don't have an explanation as to why the locale is causing this problem.

Comment: I was having the same problem, and this solved my problem. Thank you. I don't know why it didn't solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a specific reason you want to use regular expressions, and not simply `map`?

```
replace :: Char -> Char
replace '\160' = 'X'
replace c      = c

test = map replace "a\160b" == "aXb"
```

Note that if you want to work with Unicode strings, it's probably easier to use the `text` package which is designed to handle Unicode, and more efficient than `String` for larger strings.

Comment: This was just a simplified example to emphasize the problem with this very character. The actual regexp will look significantly more complex..